# Saved Outlook email opens as an attachment

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I try to open a saved Outlook email a new blank email appears with saved email as an attachment.  If I click on the attachment it opens no problem.  Why won't the saved email open directly?

Comment: Where are you trying to 'open' the saved email from. Your draft folder?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you saved an Outlook message into a ".msg" file on your hard disk, and when you double click it from Explorer, it opens in Outlook by composing a new message with it as an attachment, rather than opening the message for display?

If so, you, or some program you installed, changed the file association action associated with Outlook .msg files. Or if that isn't it, it could be the security settings preventing it from opening.

Have a look here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/outlook/thread/6bea2084-af7f-4a02-89da-c8a1066405c0